# Mongo db slow query

Tags: mongodb

My query looks like this:

```
db.Users.find({
    "Profile.Type" : {
        "$ne" : NumberInt(4)
    }, 
    "JoinDate" : {
        "$gte" : ISODate("2016-08-09T23:00:00.000+0100"), 
        "$lte" : ISODate("2016-08-10T23:00:00.000+0100")
    }, 
    "Category" : {
        "$ne" : null
    }})
```

It takes around 8 seconds to run - which seems like a long time!  There are about 2 million rows in the database, and this query matches around 10,000.

I have an index in place (that I thought should help)

```
{ 
    "Profile.Type" : 1.0, 
    "Category" : 1.0, 
    "JoinDate" : 1.0, 
    "Profile.ParentUserIds" : 1.0, 
    "Profile.AdminId" : 1.0
}
```

And also one that is just

```
{  
    "JoinDate" : 1.0
}
```

...which I mention because .explain() seems to suggest it's using the second index, not the first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try hint() to force using the first index and see if the perfomance improves (number of scanned documents should be decreased)

```
db.Users.find({
    "Profile.Type" : {
        "$ne" : NumberInt(4)
    }, 
    "JoinDate" : {
        "$gte" : ISODate("2016-08-09T23:00:00.000+0100"), 
        "$lte" : ISODate("2016-08-10T23:00:00.000+0100")
    }, 
    "Category" : {
        "$ne" : null
    }}).hint({ 
      "Profile.Type" : 1.0, 
      "Category" : 1.0, 
      "JoinDate" : 1.0, 
      "Profile.ParentUserIds" : 1.0, 
      "Profile.AdminId" : 1.0
    })
```